# Latest Zeppelin SampleCrowdsale.sol token moved outside of contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, openzeppelin

Really new to Solidity, but I was following this guide: https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6

Only, I used the latest `zeppelin-solidity` (`1.7.0`) which according to [this commit](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/commit/4d7c3cca7590e554b76f6d91cbaaae87a6a2e2e3#diff-d476f27880ccf9c2540b2a80857c39cc), they moved token creation outside the crowdsale contract.

If I have the following `TestTokenCrowdsale.sol`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/RefundableCrowdsale.sol";
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol";


/**
 * @title SampleCrowdsaleToken
 * @dev Very simple ERC20 Token that can be minted.
 * It is meant to be used in a crowdsale contract.
 */
contract SampleCrowdsaleToken is MintableToken {

  string public constant name = "Sample Crowdsale Token"; // solium-disable-line uppercase
  string public constant symbol = "SCT"; // solium-disable-line uppercase
  uint8 public constant decimals = 18; // solium-disable-line uppercase

}


/**
 * @title SampleCrowdsale
 * @dev This is an example of a fully fledged crowdsale.
 * The way to add new features to a base crowdsale is by multiple inheritance.
 * In this example we are providing following extensions:
 * CappedCrowdsale - sets a max boundary for raised funds
 * RefundableCrowdsale - set a min goal to be reached and returns funds if it's not met
 *
 * After adding multiple features it's good practice to run integration tests
 * to ensure that subcontracts works together as intended.
 */
contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale, MintedCrowdsale {

  function SampleCrowdsale(uint256 _openingTime, uint256 _closingTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet, uint256 _cap, MintableToken _token, uint256 _goal) public
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
    RefundableCrowdsale(_goal)
  {
    //As goal needs to be met for a successful crowdsale
    //the value needs to less or equal than a cap which is limit for accepted funds
    require(_goal <= _cap);
  }

}
```

Here's my `2_deploy_contracts.js`:

```
const SampleCrowdsale = artifacts.require(“./TestTokenCrowdsale.sol”)

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    const openingTime = Date.now()/1000|0 + 120;
    const closingTime = openingTime + (3600 * 1 * 1); // *1 hour *1 days
    const ethRate = new web3.BigNumber(100);
    const wallet = accounts[0];
    const cap = 100000000000000000000;
    const goal = 200000000000000000000;

deployer.deploy(SampleCrowdsale, openingTime, closingTime, ethRate, wallet, cap, goal);
};
```

When I run `turffle migrate --reset`, I get the following error:

```
~/src/test-token $ truffle migrate --reset
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0x2e09c8647174d6fd5b26e2269d3d725b75d44881f27ad735323aca8fd19a517f
  Migrations: 0xecfcab0a285d3380e488a39b4bb21e777f8a4eac
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xd656595c57159a378d57439d8f0297d077c03ec39adfdac561dbfb8260758db3
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying SampleCrowdsale...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: SampleCrowdsale contract constructor expected 7 arguments, received 6
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-contract/contract.js:390:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-contract/contract.js:374:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: tried similar solution, but:: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. at Object.callback (C:\Users\vveko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\contract.js:147:1) at C:\Users\vveko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\method.js:142:1 at C:\Users\vveko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:89:1 at C:\Users\vveko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-migrate\index.js:225:1 at C:\Use

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21880)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a constructor argument. Your MintableToken address to be specific.

Try deploying your token first, then your crowdsale and just pass in the address of that token

```
deployer.deploy(YourToken).then(function(){     
  deployer.deploy(SampleCrowdsale, openingTime, closingTime, ethRate, wallet, cap, YourToken.address, goal).then( async () => {
    const instance = await OurCrowdsale.deployed();
    const token = await instance.token.call();
    console.log('Token Address', token);
  });
});
```